# Use iteritems in a dictionary with datetime as key

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

I have a dictionary `update_fields` that has key/value pairs where the value is another dictionary:

```
{datetime.date(2016, 12, 2): {'t1030': 0, 't1045': 0, 't0645': 0, 't1645': 0, 't0600': 0, 't1415': 0, 't1000': 0, 't1430': 0, 't0700': 0, 't1800': 0, 't1715': 0, 't1630': 0, 't1615': 0, 't1945': 0, 't1730': 0, 't1530': 0, 't1515': 0, 't0830': 0, 't0915': 0, 't1245': 0, 't1300': 0, 't1600': 0, 't1900': 0, 't2000': 0, 't2115': 0, 't0715': 0}, datetime.date(2016, 12, 1): {'t1030': 0, 't1045': 0, 't0645': 0, 't1645': 0, 't0600': 0, 't1415': 0, 't1000': 0, 't1430': 0, 't0700': 0, 't1800': 0, 't1715': 0, 't1630': 0, 't1615': 0, 't1945': 0, 't1730': 0, 't1530': 0, 't1515': 0, 't0830': 0, 't0915': 0, 't1245': 0, 't1300': 0, 't1600': 0, 't1900': 0, 't2000': 0, 't2115': 0, 't0715': 0}}
```

I want to create another dictionary from each key value (or somehow extract it as-is), but when I try this:

```
for update_date in update_fields:
    timeslot_fields = {timeslot: value for (timeslot, value) in update_date.iteritems()}
```

I get `AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`

And when I try it like this:

```
for update_date, values in update_fields:
    timeslot_fields = {timeslot: value for (timeslot, value) in values.iteritems()}
```

I get `TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not iterable`

What could I be doing wrong? Could it have something to do with the fact that the outer dictionary key is a datetime? No matter what I try I can't seem to break out of the key and access its value.

Comment: `update_date` is a key to the dictionary `update_fields`.  The value is at `update_fields[update_date]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are trying to iterate on the key.

```
for update_date in update_fields:
    items = update_fields[update_date].items()
    timeslot_fields = {timeslot: value for (timeslot, value) in items}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was definitely it.

Answer (score 1):

When you are iterating over a dictionary in Python, by default, you iterate over keys. If you want to iterate over values, try `update_fields.values()` or perhaps `update_fields.itervalues()`

```
for update_date in update_fields.itervalues():
    timeslot_fields = {timeslot: value for (timeslot, value) in update_date.iteritems()}
```

And if you want to iterate over items, you should use `update_fields.items()` or `update_fields.iteritems()`

```
for update_date, values in update_fields.iteritems():
    timeslot_fields = {timeslot: value for (timeslot, value) in values.iteritems()}
```

Comment: Thank yuo for the expanded explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Change `update_date.iteritems()` to `update_fields[update_date].iteritems()`,

```
for update_date in update_fields:
    timeslot_fields = {timeslot: value for (timeslot, value) in update_fields[update_date].iteritems()}
```